# How to replace hardcoded value in pipeline.yaml which is running under buildkite tool

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, docker-buildkit, buildkite

I have a use case where I need to run the same pipeline but with a different environment variable, Like dev/qa/stage/prod.

I tried to use an environment variable to make the changes at the run time but not succeeded

**pipeline.yaml**

```
steps:
  - label: ":wrench: Run ui tests on dev"
    command: "docker run --rm -e INSTANCE=${dev} gcr.io/xyz/tests:${BUILDKITE_COMMIT:0:7}"
  - wait
```

How I am passing the env value.
[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: got the solution> edit pipeline YAML with ${INSTANCE?} and use env as INTANCE=qa.

Comment: What about
Environment variables
dev=qa